# nano editor file browser activation

Tags: file, browser, editor, nano

I use Kubuntu 14.04 (but I have the same error on Raspbian on Raspberry PI), and I use `nano` as text editor. [The documentation for `nano` says that `^T` activates "File Browser" mode](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/nano.html#The-File-Browser). However, this shortcut activates the spell function when I press it. What I doing wrong? Are there some flags to set?

Answer (score 5):

To open `nano`'s file browser, press `^R` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) + `^T` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>). `^R` changes the shortcut context to the `Read File` shortcuts instead of the default.